# jQuery refactor help needed. Pass an array as a param?

Tags: jquery

Hi I have this js that I'd like to refactor:

```
if (jQuery("#monOffHrsFrm").val() != '' && jQuery("#monOffHrsTo").val() != '') {
    jQuery("#monOffHrsFrm, #monOffHrsTo").removeClass("validationError");
}
if (jQuery("#tueOffHrsFrm").val() != '' && jQuery("#tueOffHrsTo").val() != '') {
    jQuery("#tueOffHrsFrm, #tueOffHrsTo").removeClass("validationError");
}
if (jQuery("#wedOffHrsFrm").val() != '' && jQuery("#wedOffHrsTo").val() != '') {
    jQuery("#wedOffHrsFrm, #wedOffHrsTo").removeClass("validationError");
}
if (jQuery("#thuOffHrsFrm").val() != '' && jQuery("#thuOffHrsTo").val() != '') {
    jQuery("#thuOffHrsFrm, #thuOffHrsTo").removeClass("validationError");
}
if (jQuery("#friOffHrsFrm").val() != '' && jQuery("#friOffHrsTo").val() != '') {
    jQuery("#friOffHrsFrm, #friOffHrsTo").removeClass("validationError");
}
if (jQuery("#satOffHrsFrm").val() != '' && jQuery("#satOffHrsTo").val() != '') {
    jQuery("#satOffHrsFrm, #satOffHrsTo").removeClass("validationError");
}
if (jQuery("#sunOffHrsFrm").val() != '' && jQuery("#sunOffHrsTo").val() != '') {
    jQuery("#sunOffHrsFrm, #sunOffHrsTo").removeClass("validationError");
}
```

How can I pass a [mon, tue, wed, thur, fri, sat, sun] array and take care of this with a few lines?

Thanks

Comment: Eh? Where do you want to pass that to!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var days = ['mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat','sun'];
jQuery.each(days,function(e,day){
  var a = '#'+day+'OffHrsFrm', b = '#'+day+'OffHrsTo';
  if (jQuery(a).val() != '' && jQuery(b).val() != ''){
    jQuery([a,b].join(',')).removeClass('validationError');
  }
});
```

Or as @Yads pointed out:

```
var days = ['mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat','sun']; 
for (var d = 0; d < days.length; d++){
  var a = '#'+days[d]+'OffHrsFrm', b = '#'+days[d]+'OffHrsTo';
  if (jQuery(a).val() != '' && jQuery(b).val() != ''){
    jQuery([a,b].join(',')).removeClass('validationError');
  }
}
```

I would think. (Testing it out now)

Comment: I'd just use a `for` loop. No sense in creating a function scope just to iterate through an array.

Answer (score 0):

Store the days in a [JavaScript array](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp) and use [jQuery's each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function to interate through them.